# Decode Url with special & or + characters in query parameters value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, url, string-decoding

I have met this difficulty while decoding a Base64 encoded URL with parameters

```
eg: http://www.example.com/Movements.aspx?fno=hello&vol=Bits & Pieces
```

My expected results should be: 
fno = hello
vol = Bits & Pieces

```
#Encoding:
//JAVASCRIPT                
var base64 = $.base64.encode("&fno=hello&vol=Bits & Pieces");
window.location.replace("Movements.aspx?" + base64);

#Decoding c#
string decodedUrl = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Request.Url.Query.Replace("?", ""))); // Replace is used to remove the ? part from the query string. 
string fileno = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(decodedUrl).Get("fno");
string vol = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(decodedUrl).Get("vol");
```

Actual Result:
fno = hello
vol = Bits

I have searched stackoverlow and seems I need to add a custom algorithm to parse the decoded string. But as the actual URL is more complicated than shown in this example I taought better asks experts for an alternative solution!

Tks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

If the URL were correctly encoded, you would have :

http://www.example.com/Movements.aspx?fno=hello&vol=Bits+%26+Pieces

%26 is the url encoded caract for &
and spaces will be replaced by +

In JS, use `escape` to encode correctly your url!

**[EDIT]**

Use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `escape` because like  Sani Huttunen says, 'escape' is deprecated. Sorry!

Comment: `escape` is deprecated since ECMAScript 3 and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 1):

Your querystring needs to be properly encoded. Base64 is not the correct way. Use `encodeURIComponent` instead. you should encode each value separately (although not needed in most parts in the example):

```
var qs = "&" + encodeURIComponent("fno") + "=" + encodeURIComponent("hello") + "&" + encodeURIComponent("vol") + "=" + encodeURIComponent("Bits & Pieces");
// Result: "&fno=hello&vol=Bits%20%26%20Pieces"
```

Then you don't need to Base64 decode in C#.

```
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query.Replace("?", ""));
var fileno = qs.Get("fno");
var vol = sq.Get("vol");
```

Comment: Thanks Sani. You were spot on ! I was encoding the whole query part. Your example triggered my wrong doings! Base64 is not actually necessary here but as it was implemented in the whole project I might use it as well.